# unexpectedly stopped error storing text boxes in to database table dynamically in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android application development.I have create registration  form with user name,password, email. this values should be stored in sqlite database table. retrieve the data from the table.

in **login.java** i have create the table and insert the values of registration form data in to the table dynamically.
In **databsehelper.java** extends the databaseopenHelper class overwrite the oncreate and upgrade methods.this class i used this class in login.java.

In **display.java** i am going to display the data in on success register details.

there are no errors but it gives the error on the emulator unexpectedly stopped.
I am putting code below.

**login.java**

```
package rt.prj;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;



import rt.prj.DatabaseHelper;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class realestatenew extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     public static final String DEBUG_TAG = "FullDatabase Log";
     public static final int DB_version = 1;
     //public static final String DB_name = "User.db";

     public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_users";
     //public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_temp";
     //public static final String DB_name = "User_temp";
     public static final String DB_name = "User";
public static final String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE"+TABLE_NAME+"(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT,lastname TEXT, username TEXT, password TEXT, email TEXT);";
public static final String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE tbl_users;";
     public DatabaseHelper database_helper;
     public SQLiteDatabase database;
     public SQLiteDatabase database_rd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);


        Button register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);

        //private EditText text1;

        //Registration database creation
        createDataBase();
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                realestatenew login = new realestatenew();

                                Toast.makeText(login.getApplicationContext(),"In Helper executin onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                String[] success = insertRecords();
                                if(success[0].equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                                {
                                        Intent mIntent = new Intent(realestatenew.this,DisplayUser.class);

                                        mIntent.putExtra("username",success[1]);
                                        mIntent.putExtra("password",success[2]);
                                        mIntent.putExtra("email",success[3]);
                                        startActivity(mIntent);
                                }

                        }

                });
    }
    //database create function
    void createDataBase()
    {
        if(Arrays.binarySearch(databaseList(), DB_name)>=0)
        {
                deleteDatabase(DB_name);
        }

        database_helper = new
DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext(),DB_name,null,DB_version);
        //database_helper.onCreate(database);
        database = database_helper.getWritableDatabase();
        database.setLocale(Locale.getDefault()); 
        // Set the locale

        database.setLockingEnabled(true);  

        database_rd = database_helper.getReadableDatabase();

        Toast.makeText(this, "created database",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /*
        database =
openOrCreateDatabase(DB_name,SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,
null);
        database.setLocale(Locale.getDefault()); // Set the locale
        database.setLockingEnabled(true); // SQLiteDatabase is made
thread-safe by using locks around critical sections.
        database.setVersion(1);

        database.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        */
    }

   // data  insertion
    String[] insertRecords()
    {
            Toast.makeText(this,"In insertrecords", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //database.openDatabase(DB_name,database.create(factory),ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
    final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    final EditText password= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
    final EditText email= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText04);
    Long newUserID = 0l;

    String uname  = username.getText().toString();
    String pwd = password.getText().toString();
    String emailid  = email.getText().toString();



    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("username",uname);
    values.put("password",pwd);
    values.put("email",emailid);

       //StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();
    String[] info = new String[10];


    database.beginTransaction();
    try
    {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Before calling inserting values",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            newUserID = database.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            Toast.makeText(this,"After calling inserting values",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            info[0] = newUserID.toString();
            info[1] = uname;
            info[2] = pwd;
            info[3] = emailid;


            System.out.println(newUserID);
            Toast.makeText(this, newUserID.toString(),
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Cursor c = database_rd.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null,null,null);
            LogCursorInfo(c);
            c.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
            //Transaction failed;
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
            database.endTransaction();
            database.close();
    }
    return info;
    }

    public void LogCursorInfo(Cursor c)
    {
                Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "*** Cursor Begin *** " + " Results:" +
c.getCount() + " Columns: " + c.getColumnCount());

                // Print column names
                String rowHeaders = "|| ";
                for (int i = 0; i < c.getColumnCount(); i++) {

                       rowHeaders = rowHeaders.concat(c.getColumnName(i) +"||");
                }
                Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "COLUMNS " + rowHeaders);
                //Integer rows = c.getCount();
                //Toast.makeText(this, rows.toString(), 
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Print records
                c.moveToFirst();
                while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
                        String rowResults = "|| ";
                        for (int i = 0; i < c.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                                rowResults = rowResults.concat(c.getString(i) + 
" || ");
                        }
                        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Row " + c.getPosition() + ": " + 
rowResults);
                        Toast.makeText(this, rowResults.toString(),
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Toast.makeText(this, "In LogCursorInfo",
 // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        c.moveToNext();
                }
                Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "*** Cursor End ***");
        }




}
```

**databasehelper.java**

```
package rt.prj;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

            public static final int DB_version = 1;
            public static final String DB_name = "realestate.db";
                public SQLiteDatabase database;
                public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_users";
                //public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_temp";
             public static final String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE"+TABLE_NAME+"(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT,lastname TEXT, username TEXT, password TEXT, email TEXT);";
             realestatenew login = new realestatenew();
            public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory
factory,int version)
            {
                super(context, DB_name, factory,DB_version);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
                {

               Toast.makeText(login.getApplicationContext(),"In Helper executingonCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Create the table
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_users");
                db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);

                }

                @Override
                public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                        // Housekeeping here.
                        // Implement how "move" your application data during an upgrade of schema versions
                        // There is no ALTER TABLE command in SQLite, so this generally involves
                        // CREATING a new table, moving data if possible, or deleting the old data and starting fresh
                        // Your call.
                        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_users");
                        //onCreate(database);
                }

                @Override
                public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                        super.onOpen(db);
                }
        }
```

**display.java**

```
package rt.prj;

//import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
//import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import rt.prj.*;
public class DisplayUser extends Activity
{
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                //setContentView(R.layout.userinfo);


                final String DB_name = "realestate.db";
                final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_users";
                final int DB_version = 1;
                //final  DatabaseHelper database_helper;
                //final SQLiteDatabase database_wr;


                /*
                database =
openOrCreateDatabase(DB_name,SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,
null);
        database.setLocale(Locale.getDefault()); // Set the locale
        database.setLockingEnabled(true); // SQLiteDatabase is made
thread-safe by using locks around critical sections.
        database.setVersion(1);

        if(database.isOpen())
        {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Yes database is open",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(database.isDbLockedByCurrentThread())
        {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Yes database is locked",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Cursor c = database.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null,
null,null);

        LogIn login = new LogIn();
        login.LogCursorInfo(c);
                c.close();
                */

                //LogIn login = new LogIn();
                //database_wr = login.database_helper.getWritableDatabase();
                String uname= getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
                String pwd= getIntent().getStringExtra("password");
                String email= getIntent().getStringExtra("email");

                Toast.makeText(this, uname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                View infoPanel = _createInfoPanel(uname,pwd,email);
                setContentView(infoPanel);


        }
        public View _createInfoPanel(String uname,String pwd,String
email)
        {
                LinearLayout panel = new LinearLayout(this);
                panel.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                panel.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

          // user id
                TextView Welcome = new TextView(this);
                Welcome.setText("Welcome "+uname);
                Welcome.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14f);
                Welcome.setLayoutParams(new 
LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                TextView UserName = new TextView(this);
                UserName.setText("Username:"+uname);
                UserName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14f);
                UserName.setLayoutParams(new
LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                TextView pass = new TextView(this);
                pass.setText("password:"+pwd);
                pass.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14f);
                pass.setLayoutParams(new 
LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                TextView Email = new TextView(this);
                Email.setText("E-mailID:"+email);
                Email.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14f);
                Email.setLayoutParams(new 
LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                panel.addView(Welcome);
                panel.addView(UserName);
                panel.addView(pass);
                panel.addView(Email);
                return panel;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why this is happening and I can't really read the code because it isn't formatted correctly, but if you want to store something as trivial as some text strings you really should use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Using SharedPreferences you could store and retrieve the data in about 5 lines of code.

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences();
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("email", email);
editor.putString("username", username);
editor.putString("password", password);
editor.commit();
email = prefs.getString("email");
```